# Wordpress: Points & Rewards WP_Term Error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running a multisite installation of Wordpress and I've got the WooCommerce Points & Rewards plugin installed.

When looking at the checkout, there is this error that has appeared.

```
Notice: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to int 
in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-points-and-rewards/includes
/class-wc-points-rewards-product.php on line 547
```

The code that it is referring too is:

```
$category_ids_string = implode( ',', array_map( 'intval', $category_ids ) );
```

I've tried to resolve this but I haven't been able to do so. Can anyone suggest anything that I can do to resolve this?

The website isn't due to launch until next week but the address is: http://bartonsdrinks.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$category_ids` is probably an array of term objects. It needs to be an array of single values.

So loop through the `$category_ids` and assign the term ids to an new array:

```
// I would rename your: $category_ids to: $categories cause it makes more sense
$categories = $category_ids;
$category_ids = array();

// It would be better if you changed the definition instead of above solution

if( !empty( $categories ) ){
    foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        $category_ids[] = $cat->term_id;
    }
}

$category_ids_string = implode( ',', array_map( 'intval', $category_ids ) );
```

This should probably make it work.